# ',' expected instead of ';' on Reference Declaration in JAVA

Tags: java

*Here is the class and the error is on `flyBehavir` declaration, right on the semicolon*

```java
package simUduck;

public class duck {
    void display(){

    }
    Fly flyBehaviour;
    flyBehaviour = new Fly();
}
```

*Here is the Fly class*

```java
package simUduck;

public class Fly {
    void fly(){
        
    }
}
```

I don't actually want a initialization in `duck` class, I just want a reference there and the child classes will initialize it. Any help would be appreciated.

**The following statement doesn't give any error**

`Fly flybehavior = new Fly();`

Answer (score 3):

`flyBehaviour = new Fly();` is a statement outside of a method. That is not allowed. Each statement must be inside a method, constructor or initializer block.

So either rewrite it as an initializer (as you showed in your last line) or put it into a constructor:

```
public Duck() {
  flyBehaviour = new Fly();
}
```

(Also note, that I capitalized `Duck`, because by convention all classes should be upper-case in Java).

Comment: usually there is no problem declaring as such but why there is in this case? 'That is not allowed', where exactly? If you declare it within a class, there isn't anything wrong.

Comment: You must distinguish expressions as part of a field declaration (i.e. something like `private Fly flyBehaviour = new Fly()`) and statements (i.e. "do something"-things) such as the assignment statement `flyBehaviour = new Fly()` or `System.out.println("Hello")`. The later category can only exist in some code block (methods, constructors or initializers) and aren't allowed to just "float freely in the class").